# using string methods to count characters

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to count the number of non-blank characters in a string.

It works fine when there are no leading blank spaces, but when I add 3 spaces in from, it doubles the number of non-blank characters.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class countCharacters
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
  String str1;
  int count;
  count = 0;



  BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
  str1 = dataIn.readLine();
while(str1.length() > 0)
      {


  System.out.println("The String ''" + str1 + "''");
  System.out.println("has " + str1.length() + " Characters, including all blanks.");
  for(int i=0; i < str1.length(); ++i)
    if(str1.charAt(i) !=' ')
    count++;
  str1 = str1.trim();
   System.out.println("and " + str1.length() + " Characters, trimmed of leading and trailing blanks.");
   System.out.println("and " + count + " non-blank characters.");
System.out.println("");

System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
  str1 = dataIn.readLine();
   }

  System.out.println("Program complete.");

}
}
```

Comment: Trust me - formatting your code will help you a LOT in the debugging process. How can you check your code if you can't read it! If you're using Eclipse, hit control+shift+f, and your code will be autoformatted. I honestly can't look at your code at this point because it isn't readable to me.

Comment: Isn't it better if you trim **before** counting the characters?

Comment: @MatiCicero He/she is only doing `trim` in order to output the trimmed length of the string.  The characters have already been counted by then.  It doesn't matter whether they're counted before or after the `trim`.

Comment: But if you are not counting (and omitting) white space characters, trimming before counting will be a performance improvement, since you are removing characters **you know you will not count**

Comment: That's true, but this question isn't about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it doubles the count every time?  Maybe this only happens on the second time through the main loop?

You should be resetting `count` when you enter a new string.  Otherwise, you're just adding to the `count` from the previous time through the main loop.  Add a line like `count = 0;` before the `System.out.print("Enter a string: ");` at the bottom of the main loop, or declare and initialise `count` inside the loop, rather than before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
String temp = str1.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

`temp.length()` will give you the answer.

You can get rid of temp variable if modifying `str1` is an option

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way to do this would be to just make a copy without any spaces and compare the lengths:

```
    String str1 = "  the quick brown fox  ";
    String spaceless = str1.replace(" ", "");
    System.out.println("Number of spaces: "+(str1.length() - spaceless.length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the static method:

```
Character.isWhitespace(char ch);
```

For example,

```
if(!Character.isWhitespace(str1.charAt(i)))
    count++;
```